# Psutil killing the wrong process

Tags: python-3.x, psutil

I am having a problem with my code and was wondering if you guys can help me. Here is the sample of the code:

```
PID = os.getpid() # Here i get the process id of self.
print(PID) #Here i print the id
pids = [] #Making an array for other ids
for i in range(9999): #Loop through 9999 possible pids
   pids.append(i)# +1 each loop
   print(pids[i]) 
   if pids[i] != PID: #if it is not this pid kill the program.
        try:
            psutil.Process(i).kill()
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print("nope")
   else:
        print("Same") # If it is the same pid don't kill it and pass.
        pass
```

So what is the problem?

Lets say that my PID is 20.
The "for" loop comes to 20 and says SAME and does not kill the program[Awesome!]
After that it comes to 21 and kills the process 20 [the main program it just skipped aka self...]

Why is it killing itself after not doing so?
If you have any ideas tell me. I searched around google and stack overflow but no luck.

Comment: Put a `break` after the line with `print("Same")`. Same level of indentation as the `print` statement.

Comment: It should pass to continue to kill other programs after it. Break just continues with the other code under it. Its like meant to clean the ram.

Comment: How are you actually running this? Are there multiple instances running at the same time?

Comment: Just one instance, not in a class. It just kills itself after the PID pass.... I don't get this... Logic is good and the syntax is too......

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now.

Comment: Yeah its just a simple line of code that turned out to be a huge mess. If you have any ideas on how can i fix this i would be grateful.